# Tkinter, remove redundant rows if values removed from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, iteration

I am trying to construct a production scheduling GUI in Tkinter.
A seperate piece of code will access my production schedule and paste the data into a csv file. As jobs are done in the scheduler, the list in the csv data gets smaller. As more jobs are added the list in the csv data gets longer.
The problem lies in that when the list becomes longer, it makes a certain amount of entries. The label doesn't refresh to show less entries when entries are removed from the csv file.

If i shut the tk-interface down and reopen it, it shows the correct information, so I know that I need to refresh the label, however using label.destroy() isn't doing that. I tried to make csv_label a global label so that it can be directly reference in my refresh window function so that it can destroy that exact instance of the label, but that didn't seem to work. Am I using destroy correctly?

```
# import the required modules
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
import time
import threading
import csv

#create the tk interface window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry('1024x768+-7+0')

#create a clock label to show current time
clock_label = tk.Label(window)
clock_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

#clock function to get current time
def clock():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Time: %I:%M:%S %p")
    clock_label.config(text=time)
    window.after(1000, clock)

#csv function which gets info from test.csv and pastes it into the label, situated on the window
def paste_csv():
    with open("test.csv", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        r = 0
        for col in reader:
            c = 0
            for row in col:
                # i've added some styling
                global csv_label
                csv_label = tk.Label(window, width=30, height=2, \
                        text=row, relief=tk.RIDGE, bg="white")
                csv_label.grid(row=r, column=c)
                c += 1
            r += 1

#attempt at destroying the label from the window
def refresh_window():
    csv_label.destroy()

#at every second, update the csv data on the window
def paste(delay):
  next_time = time.time() + delay
  while True:
    time.sleep(max(1, next_time - time.time()))
    try:
        paste_csv()
    except:
        print("tick1")

#at every 5 seconds, refresh the data on the window to reflect changes
def refresh(delay):
  next_time = time.time() + delay
  while True:
    time.sleep(max(4, next_time - time.time()))
    try:
        refresh_window()
    except:
        print("tick2")

#Thread initiations
threading.Thread(target=lambda: paste(1)).start()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: refresh(5)).start()

#autodisplay clock and csv data on startup
clock()
paste_csv()

#main window loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice, and so is `except Exception`.

Comment: @AMC, thanks for the heads up, will keep them out of my final tk application.

Comment: it is easier to remove all rows and columns and create again only needed rows. But it means you would have to keep all elements on some list to have access to them and `destroy()` them. OR create items in `Frame` and later you have to `destroy()` only this `Frame`

Comment: You could also consider using `ttk.Treeview` if you simply want to display your information.

Comment: You can go through all widgets returned by `root.grid_slaves()`, if it is a `Label` then call `destroy()`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can just re-run the whole tkinterface?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use threads for inserting labels and refresh.  Use `after()` is enough.  In order to remove redundant labels, you need to have a list holding the labels created and use this list to remove existing labels before creating new labels:

```
# import the required modules
import tkinter as tk
import csv
import datetime

# hold the csv labels
csv_label_list = []

#create the tk interface window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry('1024x768+0+0')

#create a clock label to show current time
clock_label = tk.Label(window)
clock_label.grid(column=1, row=0)

#clock function to update current time
def clock():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Time: %I:%M:%S %p")
    clock_label.config(text=time)
    window.after(1000, clock)

#csv function which gets info from test.csv and pastes it into the label, situated on the window
def paste_csv():
    with open("test.csv", newline="") as file:
        # remove existing labels
        for lbl in csv_label_list:
            lbl.destroy()
        csv_label_list.clear()
        # create new labels
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        r = 0
        for col in reader:
            c = 0
            for row in col:
                # i've added some styling
                csv_label = tk.Label(window, width=30, height=2,
                                     text=row, relief=tk.RIDGE, bg="white")
                csv_label.grid(row=r, column=c)
                csv_label_list.append(csv_label)
                c += 1
            r += 1
    # update every 5 seconds
    window.after(5000, paste_csv)

#autodisplay clock and csv data on startup
clock()
paste_csv()

#main window loop
window.mainloop()
```

** Note that if there are more than one columns in the first line of the CSV file, the clock will be covered by the new label.*